# Selenium WebDriver get childerns of a list

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to access an item inside a list, and the list has sub-items.
With this code I'm able to get the refernce for the list item:

```
WebElement actionBarElement = driver.findElement(By.id("top_action_bar"));
```

It returns only 1 item which is the list item itself and not the childrens.
I've been trying with multiple ways to access the childerns but with no luck, for example I used this line after that:

```
List <WebElement> abe = actionBarElement.findElements(By.xpath("//*"));
```

I've also tried:

```
List <WebElement> actionBarElements = findElements(By.id("top_action_bar"));
```

And came up with only 1 item - the reference to the list itself and not the childrens.

Seems like I haven't got the right approach yet, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code to get all the list elements under the list with id "top_action_bar" **(assuming this is the only list with id 'top_action_bar' in your page)**:

```
List <WebElement> abe = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id="top_action_bar"]//li"));
```

You can use the below code to access each elements in the list then.

```
    for(int i=0;i<abe.size();i++){

        //abe.get(i) -> code for iterating through each element
```

### }

**Update 25/11/14**

```
List <WebElement> abe = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@parent='actionbar']")); //This will fetch all 'a' elements having parent value as "actionbar"
```

You can access the elements after that using the for-loop as mentioned before.

Comment: This is actually not a ul->li tags, it works more like an emulator and the html itself shows this items list as "a href" tags, but there are about 15 "a href" at any page, the only uniuqe param is the parent param, any way I could use it?

Comment: I have added an update under title **Update 25/11/14**. Does this help ? Or do you need something else entirely ?

Comment: As I mentioned - there are more "a" under the same div and the only unique param is the "parent" which has different id. in this case I need all the "a" that has a parent with id 123 under div 678. to make it clearer - the "parent" param isn't connected to the containing div.

Comment: Edited the code now. If it doesn't help, please provide the html code snippet so that it will be easier to sort this one out..

Comment: Can't add HTML code since it belongs to a customer who's devloping a product. I'll try to reach this with other way, is it possible to get all the "a" which has a 123 value for "parent" tag? the suggested suolution won't run - seems that "parenttag" isn't applicable.

Comment: Oh! my bad.. :) Please check the code now.. I have removed the "parent tag" as that is an incorrect xpath. The updated code under **Update 25/11/14** will fetch all 'a' elements having parent with id "123"

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, the code doesn't get the required result.This is a sample of "a": <a id="Keypad" parent="actionbar">, how do I recieve all the "a" with "parent" = "actionbar". I hope this is helping you to get my point.

Comment: Oh! and here I have been thinking you are talking about some parent tag above 'a'. So, "parent", in fact, is an attribute of 'a'. I am adding the updated code above in a few. Please check that.

Comment: Simply genius, you saved me alot of time! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the elements of the list in one go by xpath:

```
List <WebElement> abe = actionBarElement.findElements(By.xpath('//ul[@id="top_action_bar"]/li'));
```

Assuming by list with elements you mean `ul`->`li` tags.

Comment: This is actually not a ul->li tags, it works more like an emulator and the html itself shows this items list as "a href" tags, but there are about 15 "a href" at any page, the only uniuqe param is the parent param, any way I could use it?